# Can't figure out GitHub repo name when I use `travis encrypt-file`

Tags: github, travis-ci

when I use `travis encrypt-file` command,throw error:

`Can't figure out GitHub repo name. Ensure you're in the repo directory, or specify the repo name via the -r option (e.g. travis <command> -r <owner>/<repo>)`

How do I use travis command to specify the repo name? I don't find on travis's docs

Answer (score 5):

A similar but more complete message can be seen in [lib/travis/cli/repo_command.rb](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/blob/dc6d47614d630fecf8220d4df78f5c747a6d9680/lib/travis/cli/repo_command.rb#L18-L25)

```
Can't figure out GitHub repo name. 
Ensure you're in the repo directory, or specify the repo name via the -r option (e.g. `travis <command> -r <owner>/<repo>`)"
GitHub repo name is invalid, it should be on the form 'owner/repo'
```

So in your case:

```
travis encrypt-file -r <owner>/<repo>
```

Or:

```
cd /path/to/GitHub/cloned/repo/locally
travis encrypt-file
```

(because in the last case, `git remote -v` shows the github remote repo url)

Speaking of remote, [J0hnG4lt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736033/j0hng4lt) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148452/cant-figure-out-github-repo-name-when-i-use-travis-encrypt-file#comment76590586_44149139):

> Caused for me by having a non standard remote name.
>   **Travis expects the remote to be called** "**`origin`**".

Comment: Caused for me by having a non standard remote name.   Travis expects the remote to be called "origin".

Comment: @J0hnG4lt Interesting, thank you. I have included oyur comment in the answer for more visibility.